# Managing privacy in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have use case where I have 2 organizations and they are sharing some data and some data is kept private. Now after couple of years, I have a requirement to share some more data or restrict some data from/to organization. Is it possible in Hyperledger Fabric? If yes please let me know how. I can see there is private data in Hyperledger fabric but the issue is that the data entered while org was not allowed to have that data will never be available for that same org after allowing that org.

If you have any idea please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 it is possible to update a private data collection configuration definition or add a new collection at chaincode upgrade time.  The updated configuration applies from the time the upgrade transaction is committed onwards. Newly added organizations will receive private data for subsequent collection transactions.

In future versions of Hyperledger Fabric, there is intent to add an option that allows newly added organizations to pull (reconcile) prior private data for the collections that they are now entitled to.