# Communications among Fabric's private data collections

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

in Fabric, can an asset created in a private data collection be transferred to another private data collection at a later point in time? How is confidentiality/privacy handled here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an asset can be transferred from one private data collection to another private data collection.  Assuming the chaincode logic retrieves the state of the asset before transferring it, the chaincode would have to be executed and endorsed on a peer that has access to the prior private data collection. The endorsing peer doesn't necessarily need access to the future private data collection (it is up to the chaincode logic to enforce this or not).

Let's say you have a private data collection per organization. Assume there is an asset in OrgA's private data collection. Chaincode can be written with access control logic such that only an OrgA client can transfer the OrgA asset to a private data collection of OrgB. The client would have to send the proposal to an OrgA peer to execute and endorse this transaction.

For more details, see the [tutorial that demonstrates transferring private assets across collections](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/secured_asset_transfer/secured_private_asset_transfer_tutorial.html).

Comment: the link has nothing about private data

Comment: the link has been fixed.